# Prime ideals and other ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This question was asked in my quiz of Ring theory and I was not able to prove it.

> Question: Show that if $I$ is not prime, then there exists ideal $I_1$ and $I_2$ such that $I$ is a proper subset of $I_1$ and I is a proper subset of $I_2$ and $I_1 I_2 \subset I$. Assume the ring to be commutative.

Attempt: If I prove it as given , then I will have to construct such ideals which is not easy for me.

I tried by proving the contrapositive : let there doesn't exists ideal $I_1$ and $I_2$ such that I is a proper subset of .... and then I is a prime ideal.

But I still not able to make any progress on this.

So, can you please help me with this?

Comment: The statement looks wrong to me. If $I$ is a proper subset of both $I_1, I_2$, then it is a proper subset of $I_1I_2$, which contains both $I_1$ and $I_2$. How come $I_1I_2\subset I$?

Comment: @kathy4k $I_1I_2$ is smaller than $I_1$ and $I_2$. For example, in $\mathbb Z$, take $I_1 = I_2 = 2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Suppose we can find $I_1,I_2$ properly containing $I$ with $I_1I_2\subset I$. So $I$ cannot be the whole ring. Let's prove that $I$ cannot be prime, i.e., there is $ab\in I$ with $a,b\notin I$.

Since $I$ is a proper subsets of $I_1,I_2$, then we can pick $a\in I_1$ and $b\in I_2$ such that $a,b\notin I$. But $ab\in I_1I_2\subset I$. Hence $I$ is not prime.

Comment: This is a proof of the converse of the statement the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

By definition, since $I$ is not prime, there exist elements $x_1, x_2\in R\setminus I$ such that $x_1x_2 \in I$.

As a first guess, we could set $I_i = \langle x_i\rangle$. Then we would definitely have $I_1I_2 \subset I$... but we wouldn't necessarily have $I\subset I_i$.

But we can fix that quite easily! Just set $I_i = \langle x_i, I\rangle$. Can you finish from here?

Equivalently, you could consider the map
$$\pi\colon R\to R/I.$$

Since $I$ is not prime, $R/I$ is not an integral domain. So there exist $x_1, x_2\in R/I$ such that $x_1x_2 = 0$.

Now let $I_i = \pi^{-1}(\langle x_i\rangle)$.